# SessionHandler becomes null in Jetty v9.4.5

Tags: java, session, jetty, session-timeout

So I am using embedded jetty server for my project application. Whenever a request comes in to specific method it has all the attributes populated in org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request object including SessionHandler, but since my code is taking significant amount of time to excecute , after some time Session and SessionHandler attribute becomes null in Request object. Due to this , obviously I am getting exception whenever I try o access session as below :

Exception in thread "Thread-19" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No SessionManager
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getSession(Request.java:1548)

Initially I thought , since my code is taking longer to complete execution , it might be that I am losing session due to timeout, so I increased the session-timeout value. But it didn't help.

Has anyone come across similar issue , please suggest me solution. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. You are probably missing a Jetty session manager in your handler list.

Instead of:

```
    server.setHandler( context );
```

do this:

```
    HandlerCollection contexts = new HandlerCollection( new org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler(), context ); 
    server.setHandler( contexts );
```